# Invalid hook call with nested component call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code in my App.jsx:

```
render() {
    return (            
        <BrowserView>
            <CreateSession />                         // works just fine
            <QrCode address={CreateSession(this)} />  // throws 'Error: Invalid hook call.'
        </BrowserView>)
}
```

CreateSession returns a string, which is fed into QrCode, to generate a Qr Code. My CreateSession looks like this:

```
const CreateSession = (props) => {

  const userVideo = useRef();
  const partnerVideo = useRef();
  const peerRef = useRef();
  const socketRef = useRef();
  const otherUser = useRef();
  const userStream = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    socketRef.current = io.connect("/");
    socketRef.current.emit("join session", props.match.params.roomID);

  // lots of code omitted, source is: https://github.com/coding-with-chaim/native-webrtc/blob/master/client/src/routes/Room.js
   

  return uuid();
};

export default CreateSession;
```

What is the correct way to call CreateSession so that it returns the uuid right into QrCode? I am aware that I could have a state property in the App.jsx that gets set to uuid, that is then passed into QrCode, but is it possible to do it this way?

Comment: That isn't a functional component, it doesn't return JSX or any kind of call to `createElement`. Hooks can be called in components, not regular functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn your `CreateSession` component into a wrapper.

```js
const CreateSession = (props) => {

  const userVideo = useRef();
  const partnerVideo = useRef();
  const peerRef = useRef();
  const socketRef = useRef();
  const otherUser = useRef();
  const userStream = useRef();

  const [uuid, setUuid] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    socketRef.current = io.connect("/");
    socketRef.current.emit("join session", props.match.params.roomID);

    // lots of code omitted, source is: https://github.com/coding-with-chaim/native-webrtc/blob/master/client/src/routes/Room.js
  
    setUuid(uuid());
  });
  
  if (uuid === null) {
    return null;
  }

  return (<>{props.children(uuid)}</>)
};

export default CreateSession;
```

Here is the usage.

```js
render() {
  return (            
    <BrowserView>
      <CreateSession>
        {(uuid) => (<QrCode address={uuid} />)}
      </CreateSession>
    </BrowserView>
  )
}
```